# Local CSS rendering as unicode characters

Tags: html, css, iis

I have an IIS container that is serving static pages and my local CSS won't render.

Here are my stylesheet links.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

I have no issues with the bootstrap cdn.

FireFox dev tools shows the following for main.css

```
栮慥⁤ൻ †瀠摡楤杮琭灯›〲硰഻
```

I've tried changing the locations of my css file and it has no impact.

Navigating to //hostname/main.css shows the contents of the css with no issues.

```
.head {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.fr {
    float: right;
}

.fl {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.head a:link {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: auto;
}

.navbar-list {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-list > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: what encoding did you store the css file with? use the `charset` attribute to specify your encoding.

Comment: It sounds like css stop working because the page and css file are using different charset. Have you tried to specify charset for both of them?